# sumar números positivos y negativos report viewer

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc

**esta es una lista en report viewer, como hago para que me sume los negativos y los positivos.**

```
6,250.00
 -281.25
  -74.97
```

**intente con esto:**

```
=IIF(Fields!Valor.Value > 0, sum(Fields!Valor.Value) , sum(Fields!Valor.Value))
```

**tambien**

```
=SUM((IIF(Fields!Valor.Value < 0,0,Fields!Valor.Value)))
```

**hay alguna forma ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si **Fields!Valor** no esta trabajando como debe, entonces estas tomando el tipo de valor por defecto del dataset, utiliza conversión

```
=SUM(cdbl(IIF(Fields!Valor.Value > 0,Fields!Valor.Value,0)))
```

como mandejas numeros con digitos utiliza double